# Treate DENSITY_560 as XXXHIGH or XXHIGH?

Tags: android, imageview, screen-density

In the documents, android says:

```
/**
 * Intermediate density for screens that sit somewhere between
 * {@link #DENSITY_XXHIGH} (480 dpi) and {@link #DENSITY_XXXHIGH} (640 dpi).
 * This is not a density that applications should target, instead relying
 * on the system to scale their {@link #DENSITY_XXXHIGH} assets for them.
 */
```

Android think its a XXXHIGH(4X) screen.

But I have another function call `getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.line_list_item_height)`,
 it returns 3X height, it is so strange, how to fix this?

- Device is Nexus 6p
- Compile sdk version is  23
- I use a viewpage inside a listview, so must calculate a height to prop up the  viewpage.